# AWS ubuntu instance can't reach the world

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I created a new ubuntu instance in AWS, I can ssh connect to it successfully.
However when I try to install packages using this command, it won't work :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2  
...
...
0% [Connecting to ap-southeast-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.23)]^Cubuntu@ip-10-1-0-99:/etc$
```

This never moves forward !

I tried ping google.com.au, also no response.

Here is the VPC config of AWS:

```
Network ACL : 

Outbound:
Rule #  Type        Protocol    Port Range  Destination Allow / Deny
100 ALL Traffic ALL     ALL     0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW
*   ALL Traffic ALL     ALL     0.0.0.0/0   DENY

Inbound : 
Rule #  Type        Protocol    Port Range  Source  Allow / Deny
10  HTTP (80)   TCP (6) 80  0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW
120 HTTPS (443) TCP (6) 443 0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW
140 SSH (22)    TCP (6) 22  0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW
*   ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0   DENY
```

security Group outbound settings :

```
Type    Protocol    Port Range  Destination 
ALL     Traffic     ALL     ALL     0.0.0.0/0
```

Routing table setting:

```
Destination     Target      Status  Propagated
10.1.0.0/24 local       Active  No
0.0.0.0/0   igw-cfe30caa    Active  No
```

What could be wrong here ?

EDIT: nslookup & dig command works fine!

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like DNS is broken for you. Try using 'dig google.com.au' to see if DNS can do address lookups.

Comment: Do you launch ec2 instance with your own AMI image or amazon ami? Seems your image has issue.

Comment: Actually dig google.com.au works fine ! also nslookup command works. I am using AWS's ami, just used the wizard

Comment: @askanaan - try 'dig +notcp google.com.au' since apt-get and ping may be using UDP instead of TCP for domain lookups.

Comment: I enabled all inbound traffic and everything works fine, I was able to use sudo apt-get install apache2  . I was under impression enabling all outbound traffic should be enough. 
Any idea what port should enabled in inbound traffic to help here ?

Comment: @askanaan - try the port 53 both UDP and TCP.

Comment: Where is inbound security group. Give us inbound security group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your inbound network ACL is only allowing traffic addressed to *inbound* TCP ports 22, 80, and 443.  It doesn't allow the responses for your outbound requests, on your ephemeral ports.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   61000
```

You need a rule in the network ACL to allow TCP 32768 through 61000... or, better, don't use the inbound network ACL at all -- set it back to the default, to allow all.

You almost certainly don't need to use network ACLs unless you have a particularly complex network configuration.  The inbound rules in the security group are usually sufficient to control access to an instance.  Inbound security group rules deny by default, and unlike Network ACLs, which are stateless packet filters, security groups are stateful, TCP session-aware.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html#VPC_Security_Comparison

Important: **do not** add the ephemeral port rule discussed above to the security group inbound rules.  Since security groups are stateful, you only want to "allow" traffic in the direction where you want TCP sessions to be initiated.  Responses to established TCP sessions are allowed automatically by security group rules, but not network ACL rules, because they're implemented differently.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html

Comment: Many Thanks! I removed the access from the security group and still I can access the internet resources

Comment: You deserve a beer. I've been battling my VPC for 2 hours, because I couldn't get out to the internet from a new instance. I'd deleted the ALL TRAFFIC rule on the network ACL and added an ssh-only rule. Not sure how I missed that so many times. I swear I looked at the Network ACLs 100 times. anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
*   ALL Traffic ALL     ALL     0.0.0.0/0   DENY - Wrong

*   ALL Traffic ALL     ALL     0.0.0.0/0   Allow - Right
```

Please allow Outbound, if you want to connect to external servers like google.com
or even want to update- sudo apt-get update

You can allow the outbound using AWS front-end goto Security Groups -> Outbound

Make sure you select the right group for your AWS instance